# Escape a primefaces/jsf page that has required fields

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces

I have a jsf page with

`<h:inputText required="true">` attribute.
When I click on my add button, I want to see an error if the field is blank.

I have a `<f:message>` to display this.

But how can I escape (cancel) the page with that field blank?  In my case it continually posts the error message and I have to enter something in the field to go to another page.

Comment: So, why is the component required if you want to go through this page without inserting a value in this field?

Comment: use p:button for cancel

Answer (score 4):

If your cancel button is a ***POST*** requests e.g. `<p:commandButton>`,`<h:commandButton>`, `<p:commandLink>`,  or `<h:commandLink>`

You can put your cancel button **outside the form** that has the  `<h:inputText>` so that form is not submitted

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText value="#{bean.string}" required="true"/>
</h:form>
<h:form>
     <p:commandButton value="Cancel" action="anotherpage.xhtml"/>
</h:form>
```

If you are navigating without any actions or method invocation, then you can use ***GET*** requests e.g. `<h:button>`, `<p:button>`, `<h:link>` or `<h:outputLink>`.

**Example:**

```
 <h:form>
    <h:inputText value="#{bean.string}" required="true"/>
    <p:button value="Cancel" outcome="anotherpage.xhtml"/>
 </h:form>
```

Comment: there is no such thing as THE "correct" answer. There is almost always a better (even if unpractical) answer given a specific scenario, but never the "correct" one. Any answer that solves the problem, even the ugliest, is a correct one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `immediate="true"` in your `<p:commandButton>`. Then it will skip the validation.

For example:

```
<p:commandButton action="#{managedBean.action}" value="Cancel" immediate="true" />
```

Comment: immediate="true" will skip validation phase, so by setting this to commandbutton will work

Comment: Using `immediate="true"` in the command button basically skip few phases in JSF lifecycle. It's better to understand how JSF lifecycle works.

Following is a good article to read.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jsf2/

Answer (score 1):

Just don't process the form on submit if you want to cancel or navigate away.

I.e. don't do

```
<h:form>
    ...
    <p:commandButton value="Cancel" action="#{bean.cancel}" />
</h:form>
```

But just do

```
<h:form>
    ...
    <p:commandButton value="Cancel" action="#{bean.cancel}" process="@this" />
</h:form>
```

Or, better if you're only returning a navigation outcome in `cancel()` method anyway

```
<h:form>
    ...
    <p:button value="Cancel" outcome="otherpage.xhtml" />
</h:form>
```